# How to add a number to a timestamp in Excel

Tags: excel

I've got two columns, one of them is a timestamp field with the format as `yyyy-mm-dd h:mm:ss` and another is a Duration_in_hours column which has a number.

I need to add the duration to the `h`. Any suggestions on how I can go about doing so?

EDIT:
The cell format for timestamp is 'Custom' (If that matters).

Answer (score 1):

If you simply need to add the hours and let the formatting do the rest (i.e. if there's enough hours in `h` to change the date `dd`, then change the date as well, and any other applicable fields), then you simply do it like this:

```
=A1+(A2/24)
```

Where:

- `A1` has the timestamp field.
- `A2` has the duration in hours.

This works because a unit of `1` in excel is equivalent to 1 day. Dividing by 24 gives it in terms of hours.

Comment: That just says `#VALUE!`. :(

Comment: @omgitsdev Hmm, the custom formatting shouldn't be a problem, and that's working even if the date is a text string on my Excel 2010. Try `=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,11,LEN(F16)))+(A2/24)` just to see what happens?

Comment: What is the F16 for? Not sure what that's referencing. :)

Comment: @omgitsdev Oops, that's supposed to be A1. I was trying it on the cell F6 and didn't substitute all the cell addresses it seems!